# Haskell: How to return a random element that is not part of a list

Tags: list, haskell

How would  I write a function that takes a list as an argument and returns a random element that is not a part of the list in Haskell?

```
randomElement [a", "b", "c"]

"z"-- returns any string except "a", "b", "c"
```

So far I've written a function that checks recursivly if an element is in a list.

```
inList _ [] = False
inList n (x:xs)
   | x == n = True
   | otherwise = inList x xs
```

However I don't know how to then modify this function or how to write an additional  function that then returns an element that's not a member of the list.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: You need to define the question better. How is `randomElement` supposed to know what the "universe" of possible results is? What happens if the list you want excluded is equal to the universe? Also, do you know about the `System.Random` package?

Comment: One trivial answer for strings: `randomElement xs = 'A' : concat xs`. This will always output a string which is not in `xs`. But presumably that isn't what you meant.

Comment: One more thing: your `inList` function is `elem` in the Prelude. And the last line of your function should be `| otherwise = inList n xs`

Comment: @BlueCode6 Based on your example, I suspect that you may be looking for a function which, given a list of _printable ASCII characters_ (rather than strings), will return a random printable ASCII character not in the list. Is my suspicion at all correct? [1/2]

Comment: @BlueCode6 [2/2] If so, one approach would be to simply generate a list of all printable ASCII characters, subtract the input list, then take a random character from the new list. Otherwise, I have to say that I am stumped by your requirements… given that there are infinitely many strings not in the input list, it is impossible to select a value not in the list in a truly random way, unless you specify more precisely what you mean by ‘random’.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: nitpick: `randomElement [xs] == xs` for `xs = repeat 'A'`.

Comment: When we are doing random selection we must know what elements we are selecting from. In your example is 12 an acceptable output? Is "the brown fox" ok? When you are writing randomElement ["a", "b", "c"], it appears that you are talking about Strings (double quoted "a" is quite different from single quoted 'a')

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the diagonalization argument that shows that `String` is not countably infinite. Unlike the other proposed solutions, this one actually guarantees that it is different from any element in the list passed in, while still being lazy enough to work with infinite lists.

```
distinctHead :: String -> Char
distinctHead "" = 'a'
distinctHead ('a':_) = 'b'
distinctHead (c:_) = pred c

distinct :: [String] -> String
distinct = map distinctHead . zipWith drop [0..]
```

Comment: what is `'b'`? where does it come from? I interpret the problem as having to construct the answer from the thing we are given as an argument. if you bring in the type-specific knowledge, of course you can do lots and lots of things with it.  for the finite inputs, my solution works, and for the infinite, I get a feeling it's impossible.

Comment: @WillNess `'b'` is a `Char`. Yours uses type-specific knowledge, too; the analogous question I'd ask you is "What is `"random "`? Where does it come from?". It isn't impossible for infinite inputs; the claim is very weird, given that this answer shows how to do it.

Comment: @WillNess And, for what it's worth, this answer can be adapted so that `distinct :: (Eq a, Big a) => [[a]] -> [a]`, where `Big` is a type class proving that a type has at least two distinct elements; something like `class Eq a => Big a where big :: (a, a)` with law `fst big /= snd big`. So not much type-specific knowledge is needed at all.

Comment: yeah, don't know what I was thinking there with that comment. :( I do the same in my answer, too, with the `"random " ++`...